# How to run this Google App Script with a checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to make this script run from an edit on a checkbox (Checkbox is on G10)

It's supposed to convert a sheet to PDF, add a specific name, and then saves it into a folder.

I have not been able to get it to work, I am very much a beginner and I am willing to learn.

Thank you!

```
function exportSheet() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheetName = 'Fact.'; //Change 'Main Sheet' to the name of your main sheet
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheetName);
  var name = mainSheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
  var name2 = mainSheet.getRange('C7').getValue(); //Gets the pdf name from cell B6
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); //Pulls all sheets as an array

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Iterates through all sheets
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== mainSheetName) { //Hides all sheets that are not the main one
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }
  DriveApp.getFolderById('1CH9BY-Tm55W2xkZULjvD2xUsaeN42sbR')
    .createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name2 + " " + "Fact. # " + name +".pdf")); //Exports the main sheet

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Brings back all sheets that were hidden
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
}
```

I have been trying to make this script run from an edit on a checkbox (Checkbox is on G10)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function exportSheet(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Fact." && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart == 10 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var name = sh.getRange('C4').getValue();
    var name2 = sh.getRange('C7').getValue();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Iterates through all sheets
      if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== mainSheetName) { //Hides all sheets that are not the main one
        sheets[i].hideSheet()
      } DriveApp.getFolderById('1CH9BY-Tm55W2xkZULjvD2xUsaeN42sbR')
        .createFile(e.source.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name2 + " " + "Fact. # " + name + ".pdf")); //Exports the main sheet
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Brings back all sheets that were hidden
        sheets[i].showSheet()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the following errors : 11:01:31 AM Notice Execution started
11:01:32 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
exportSheet @ Untitled.gs:2

Comment: You cannot run this code without supplying the event object like the onEdit trigger does.

Comment: I managed to get it to work part way, but still stuck. The document is not saved and the sheets do not reappear.

Comment: I figured it out! It was only working halfway because it was a simple trigger, I needed to set up a Installable Trigger.

Comment: That's great.  Good work on realizing it need to be installable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script to run when something is edited in a Google Sheet, you need to create something called a "simple trigger" – in this, case, an "onEdit" trigger. When you create the trigger from the Apps Script editor, the configuration screen will prompt you to select a function to run when the trigger is fired. In this case you would select "exportSheet" from the drop-down.

You can read more about onEdit in the [Google developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

It sounds like you want to ensure that a particular checkbox is selected before you actually run the code (i.e. cell G10). If that's the case, you will need to update your function to assess whether it should proceed or not. To do that, you need to get the value of cell G10 and see if it's TRUE (the value returned for a selected checkbox in Google Sheets).

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet(); 
  if(sh.getName() == 'Fact.' && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.range.rowStart == 10 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheetName = 'Fact.'; //Change 'Main Sheet' to the name of your main sheet
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheetName);
  var name = mainSheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
  var name2 = mainSheet.getRange('C7').getValue(); //Gets the pdf name from cell B6
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); //Pulls all sheets as an array
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== mainSheetName)
    sheets[i].hideSheet()
    DriveApp.getFolderById('1CH9BY-Tm55W2xkZULjvD2xUsaeN42sbR')
    .createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name2 + " " + "Fact. # " + name +".pdf")); //Exports the main sheet
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) 
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
}
```